# How to draw vertical line's perpendicular to an SVG Arc at a given point like positioning a text using textPaths's startOffset ( SVG METER )?

Tags: html, css, svg

In the given below SVG meter, How to create / fix the following :

1. Vertical lines exactly below the reading value ( `textPath` ), to recreate a circular scale ?
2. And how to fix the overflowing values to be visible, which are at each end's of the `path` both at `startOffset: "0%"` and `startOffset: "100%"` ?

**CODEPEN :** https://codepen.io/sparkeplug/pen/OJvmLOB

**SAMPLE IMAGE FOR RECREATION :**

[image: sample recreation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easier to handle this case if you can work in degrees. Your arc had a specific starting point (10,50) and therefore it was not easy to calculate other positions (like the small lines). I changed the "starting point" to the rotation point of the meter hand and replaced the arc/path
with a circle. All the numbers also have this starting point and are just rotated together with the small lines. I also "replaced" the meter hand so that it is easier to rotate that according to a given value.

```js
document.forms.form01.range.addEventListener('change', e => {
  document.querySelector('#meterHand path').setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${e.target.value})`);
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <input name="range" type="range" min="-25" max="25" value="0"/>
</form>
<section class="container">
  <svg class="svg" width="300" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <g stroke="black" stroke-width="1">
      <circle cx="50" cy="110" r="100" fill="none"
        stroke-dasharray="50 360" stroke-dashoffset="-245"
        pathLength="360"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(50 110)" text-anchor="middle"
      stroke="black" font-size="4" font-weight="bold"
      stroke-width="0">
      <g transform="rotate(-25) translate(0 -100)">
        <text y="-2">-50</text>
        <line y2="4" stroke-width="1" />
      </g>
      <g transform="rotate(-20) translate(0 -100)">
        <text y="-2">-40</text>
        <line y2="4" stroke-width="1" />
      </g>
      <g transform="rotate(-15) translate(0 -100)">
        <text y="-2">-30</text>
        <line y2="4" stroke-width="1" />
      </g>
      <g transform="rotate(-10) translate(0 -100)">
        <text y="-2">-20</text>
        <line y2="4" stroke-width="1" />
      </g>
      <g transform="rotate(-5) translate(0 -100)">
        <text y="-2">-10</text>
        <line y2="4" stroke-width="1" />
      </g>
      <g transform="rotate(0) translate(0 -100)">
        <text y="-2">0</text>
        <line y2="4" stroke-width="1" />
      </g>
      <g transform="rotate(5) translate(0 -100)">
        <text y="-2">10</text>
        <line y2="4" stroke-width="1" />
      </g>
      <g transform="rotate(10) translate(0 -100)">
        <text y="-2">20</text>
        <line y2="4" stroke-width="1" />
      </g>
      <g transform="rotate(15) translate(0 -100)">
        <text y="-2">30</text>
        <line y2="4" stroke-width="1" />
      </g>
      <g transform="rotate(20) translate(0 -100)">
        <text y="-2">40</text>
        <line y2="4" stroke-width="1" />
      </g>
      <g transform="rotate(25) translate(0 -100)">
        <text y="-2">50</text>
        <line y2="4" stroke-width="1" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="meterHand" transform="translate(50 110)">
      <path transform="rotate(0)"
        d="m -0.5 10 v -90 l 0.5 -10 l 0.5 10 v 90 z"
        stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" fill="red"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

**The text**

`<textPath>` text will not be drawn before the start, or after the end, of the line. That's because there is no line for which to determine the orientation of the characters.  You would either need to either:

1. extend the path used for `<textPath>` further on each end.  But obviously that will mess with your percentages.  The extended path will need to match the drawn one.  Working out the new start and end points of the arc will thus probably require some trigonometry.  Or
2. Position and rotate the text yourself.  This will require some trigonometry.

**The tick marks**

To position the ticks, you will to either:

1. Draw eleven vertical tick marks at the '0' point. Then rotate the non-zero ones left or right by X degrees. The value of X will need to be determined by working out what number of degrees is equivalent to +/-10 units on your meter.  Also the ticks will need to be rotated around the centre point of the circular arc. Or
2. Position and draw the tick marks yourself. This will require some trigonometry.

Answer (score 1):

crwahl his answer as native JavaScript Web Component `<svg-meter value="20">`

```html
<input id=setMeter oninput="meter1.value=this.value" type="range" min="-50" max="50" value="10" />
<br>
<svg-meter id=meter1 value="20"></svg-meter>
<svg-meter id=meter2 value="-20"></svg-meter>
<svg-meter id=meter3 value="40"></svg-meter>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-meter", class extends HTMLElement {
    set value(v) {
      this.querySelector('[hand]').setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${v*(this.angle_step/this.step)})`);
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      Object.assign(this, {
        min: -50,
        angle_min: -25,
        angle_step: 5,
        step: 10,
        color: "darkgreen",
        scalecolor: "green"
      });
      this.innerHTML = `
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" height="180">
  <circle cx="50" cy="110" r="100" fill="none"
          stroke="${this.scalecolor}" stroke-width="1"
          stroke-dasharray="50.65 360" stroke-dashoffset="-245.1" pathLength="360"/>
  <g transform="translate(50 110)" stroke="${this.scalecolor}">
      ${Array(11).fill().map((d,idx)=>{
            return `<g transform="rotate(${this.angle_min+(idx*this.angle_step)}) translate(0 -100)">
         <text y="-2" fill="${this.color}" text-anchor="middle" font-size="4" font-weight="bold" stroke-width="0">${this.min+(idx*this.step)}</text>
         <line y2="4" stroke-width="1"/></g>`;    
    }).join("")}
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(50 110)">
    <path hand transform="rotate(0)" d="m-0.5 10v-90l0.5-10l0.5 10v90z" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" fill="red"/>
  </g>
</svg>`;
      this.value = this.getAttribute("value") || 0;
    }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use css property:

```
.svg #meterHand{
   transform: rotate(-20deg);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes @Prabhu Create grid like this after number's grid:
<g>
        <text text-anchor="middle" font-size="8" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(0 -2)" class="lines">
        <textPath href="#meter" startOffset="0%">|</textPath>
        <textPath href="#meter" startOffset="10%">|</textPath>...
      </text>
    </g>